# LightInject - How to Register Multiple Interfaces to a Single Service?

Tags: light-inject

How do I register a service that implements 4 interfaces?

For example: `class Foo : IFoo, IBar, IApp, ISee { ... }`

I was hoping for something like this:
`container.Register<IFoo, IBar, IApp, ISee, Foo>();`

But it appears this signature is for passing various types into a factory, in this case a factory that takes 4 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

For those how also have this same question. Here is one possible way of solving it:

```
container.Register(_ => new Foo(), new PerScopeLifetime());
container.Register<IFoo>(factory => factory.GetInstance<Foo>());
container.Register<IBar>(factory => factory.GetInstance<Foo>());
container.Register<IApp>(factory => factory.GetInstance<Foo>());
container.Register<ISee>(factory => factory.GetInstance<Foo>());
```

In my specific case I also need to ensure that there was only one instance of Foo() within each scope. I.e. web request.